# Minimizing time of a rotating pole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, torque

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now but I'm not sure exactly what I must do in this scenerio.

The scenerio is as follows:

There is a pole of arbitrary length attached to a point of rotation, that stands vertically (I assume it is at (0,1)). The pole also begons from rest. I simply want to find out how much torque I must apply to the rod in order for it to reach the horizontal position (assuming again (1,0)) as fast as possible.

Now my logic behind this was I have the equation

- Torque = $\tau$
- Angular Acceleration = $\alpha$
- Time = $t$
- Angular speed = $\omega$
- Rotational Inertia = $I$

I started with 
$T = I\alpha$

I then changed $\alpha$ into $(\omega_f - \omega_i)/t$ and because it starts at rest, $\omega_i = 0$ so in the end it is $\omega_f/t$

The equation the became 
$\tau = I(\omega_f/t)$

Rearrangement of terms will get you $t=I\omega_f/\tau$

Which would imply that as $\tau$ increases as $t$ gets smaller. Is this derivation correct?

Comment: By writing $A=(w_f-w_i)/t$, you are using average acceleration, not the instantaneous one. Maybe that's what you want, but I think you will want to use the kinematic equations for constant accelerating motion. Further, is this pole massive? I don't see the torque due to gravity acting on the pole.

Comment: As stated, there is no maximum torque and minimum time-to-horizontality; the more torque you apply the faster the pole will move. Are there constraints you haven't included?

Answer (score 1):

The angular motion equivalent of Newton's second law is:

$$ T = I \dot{\omega} $$

If the torque $T$ is constant then integrating this once gives us an expression for the angular velocity:

$$ \omega(t) = \frac{T}{I} t + \omega_0 $$

where $\omega_0$ is the angular velocity at time zero. Integrating again gives an expression for the angle rotated:

$$ \theta(t) = \tfrac{1}{2}\frac{T}{I} t^2 + \omega_0 t + \theta_0 $$

where $\theta_0$ is the angle at time zero. These should be immediately recognisable as the angular versions of the SUVAT equations:

$$ \begin{align}
F &= ma \\
v &= u + at \\
s &= ut + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2
\end{align}$$

In your case it isn't clear if you want to include the effect of gravity, but let's ignore gravity for now. In that case since $\omega_0 = 0$ and we can choose our starting angle so that $\theta = 0$, and putting in the final angle of rotation as $\pi/2$ we get:

$$ \theta = \tfrac{1}{2}\frac{T}{I} t^2 = \frac{\pi}{2} $$

or rearranging for $t$ gives:

$$ t = \sqrt{\frac{\pi\,I}{T}} $$

Answer (score 0):

I believe after reading my question I didn't necessarily explain the problem with enough detail.

So providing more background, assume the situation is that the pole has a mass of m and length of l. They're not insignificant to the problem therefore gravity is needed in the equation (I forgot about it entirely when I asked the question).

As far as constraints go, the system is being powered by a motor with a stall torque of 2.42 N*m and a max rpm of 5310 (I'm assuming a straight line between these points on a graph)

I was trying to get an idea of how I would even approach the problem but Im lost. My issue comes with I don't know how to calculate the optimal way to set up this system so that the pole can reach the horizontal position the fastest.

Hopefully this is enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Asking "I simply want to find out how much torque I must apply to the rod in order for it to reach the horizontal position (assuming again (1,0)) as fast as possible" makes very little sense - the more torque you apply the faster the rod will accelerate. Your amplifying answer, which specifies a motor torque, really doesn't make any sense, either.

But let me go out on a limb here, and ask the question I think you're trying to ask.

Given a motor with stall torque of 1.42 N-m and a no-load speed of 5310 rpm, and given a uniform cylindrical rod of length L and mass M, mounted vertically on a motor hub with the axis of the motor horizontal, at what length $L_1$  from the lower end of the rod should the motor hub be mounted to allow rotation of the rod by 90 degrees in minimum time.

If the hub is mounted at the center of the rod ($L_1 = L/2$), the moment of inertia will be minimized, but there is no assist from gravity as the rod tilts. If the hub is mounted at the end of the rod ($L_1 = 0$) the moment of inertial is greater, but gravity causes added acceleration as the rod tilts away from vertical.

You can consider the rod to be made up of two rods, one on each side of the hub, one of length $L_1$, and the other of length $L - L_1$, with masses proportional. Each rod has a moment of inertia, and the total MOI is simply the sum of the two.

Additionally, each rod will have a center of mass halfway from the end to the hub, and gravitational attraction will provide a torque proportional to the sine of the angle from vertical, although one will be of the opposite sign as the other.

Adding the two torques will give a total torque, which will provide an angular acceleration. Integrating the acceleration twice will give angle as a function of time, and this can be used to determine the total torque as a function of time and position.

Finding a function for the time to rotate 90 degrees, differentiate with respect to $L_1$ and find the minimum.